# UITableView sectionIndexTitlesForTableView and scrollingIndicator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When my `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` return something(not nil), default scrollView scrolling indicator of my UITableView disappears. How can I show it?

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
[self.tableView flashScrollIndicators];
```

and they will flash to show the user that they are there. This is usually put in `viewDidAppear`.

It actually flash the `scroll indicators`.